# Expected behavior for history when a toggle button changes the section

Tags: toggle, history

I have a search based website where the user can search two different sections in the same manner. Let’s say one section is named *Jawn* and the other is *Moo*. The user begins the section in *Moo* preforms a search and is then taken to the *Moo* page search results. The user then clicks the *Jawn* button in the toggle and then clicks the back button.

[image: Moo state]

[image: Jawn state]

Should the user expect to land on *Jawn* or *Moo*?

Comment: Does clicking the Jawn button keep the Moo page search results intact? How does the interface change when Jawn is clicked?

Comment: The results returned from the server will be different but the query remains the same. I posted some images above. Thanks for your questions Andy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Jawn represents a significant change in both color and content, I would expect to go back to Moo.

This opinion is also based on past experience with other search interfaces like Google. Within Google, if I perform a search under the default "All" category, then toggle from "All" to "Images", then click the back button, I am taken back to "All".